# Laravel 5.6 get user in Routes issue

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, routes

How to get an id of the user?

**app/routes/web.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{
    var_dump(Auth::user());
}
```

It returns null.

Simple things made difficult.. Also there is no reliable explanation

How to handle this?

Comment: First make sure your user is actually authenticated with the result of Auth::check(). If so you can than continue with the request with Auth::user()->id. You are getting null because noone is currently logged in.

Comment: There is no issue with authentication, I just can't get `Auth::user()` in the Route  group.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined any route, try this instead:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        dd(Auth::user());
    });
});
```

Change the '/' to what ever you like, does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks. It works but it doesn't solve my problem. Why I just can't get `Auth::user()` in the route group? I need to check user's id first and then distribute routes in the route group so that I'll make a restriction to the bunch of routes by user id.